# How to get the Linkedin session cookie from console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, session-cookies

Do you know how to get the Linkedin "session cookie" from chrome console ?

```
document.cookie
```

I do not return the "session cookie". How to get the session cookie please ?

Comment: Could you provide more info, such as the name of the cookie you want?

Comment: thanks for your feecback, the Linkedin session cookie name is **li_at**

Answer (score 0):

The cookie `li_at` is marked as HttpOnly. This means that you can not access the cookie through console. This is done to prevent possible XSS attacks from stealing a users' tokens. You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies.

You can check if a cookie is marked as HttpOnly by going under `Application` and then `Cookies`. If the `HTTP` field is checked you are unable to access it through console.
[image]